# R: is it possible to export kabble to svg image

Tags: r, svg, kable

R has a great library to format tables.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

Is it possible to export the output as svg image?
So far I could only find a way to create a png but resolution is not professional grade.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can't export *directly* to a .svg table.

With `svg()` or `svglite()` we can only save *plots* with this extension. The same applies to .tiff.

**An example:**

We can make a 300 dpi .png picture.

```
kable(mtcars, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
     kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>%
     row_spec(1, color = "red") %>%
     as_image()
```

or generate a LaTeX-code **deleting** last string `as_image()`.

```
kable(mtcars, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
         kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>%
         row_spec(1, color = "red")
```

We can **convert** small tables to SVG with [this resource](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

Also take a look at Inkspace: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255470/compile-tex-directly-into-svg-using-the-command-line

Comment: interestingly `%>% save_kable("test_kable.pdf")` produces a pdf that contains a vector graph table. So it should be possible

Comment: @RockScience yes, it's also a solution. But we can't do it directly (make a svg). 300 dpi isn't enough for your deeds?